# Why does the google sheet properties stays undefined after I set them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

its my first time here, I hope I did it right. I'm new to google sheet scripts and I'm trying to use the script properties of the Properties Service, but I can't set the properties, they stay undefined. Here is the code that's not working:

```
function SetProperties(){
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('EMAIL_ROW', '1');
  Browser.msgBox("EMAIL_ROW = " + scriptProperties.getProperties["EMAIL_ROW"]);
};
```

I'm calling it from the onOpen event. I put a message box there to see the value of the property after the assignment and it shows as undefined. I can't understand what is wrong with that... looks exactly as shown in google's tutorial.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProperties()` is the method of Class Properties. In this case, it is required to run as the function. So please add `()` as follows.

#### From:

```
Browser.msgBox("EMAIL_ROW = " + scriptProperties.getProperties["EMAIL_ROW"]);
```

#### To:

```
Browser.msgBox("EMAIL_ROW = " + scriptProperties.getProperties()["EMAIL_ROW"]);
```

or

```
Browser.msgBox("EMAIL_ROW = " + scriptProperties.getProperties().EMAIL_ROW);
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the value from only the key of `EMAIL_ROW`, you can also use `Browser.msgBox("EMAIL_ROW = " + scriptProperties.getProperty("EMAIL_ROW"));` as the argument.

#### References:

- [getProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getproperties)
- [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey)

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for editing it and your always support. I miss-copied the value of `["EMAIL_ROW"]`. I always wish I could upvote to the edit.

Comment: The first two options works like a charm, thank you. But the one in the 'note' gives me this error: > Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for PropertiesService.Properties.getProperties.  at onEdit(macros:101:43)

Comment: @Épicerie Le Pont Vert Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At the Note section, `getProperty` method is used. In this case, this is different from `getProperties`. If you run `scriptProperties.getProperties("EMAIL_ROW")`, such error occurs. If my understanding is correct, please test `scriptProperties.getProperty("EMAIL_ROW")` instead of `scriptProperties.getProperties("EMAIL_ROW")`. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that difference. It works perfectly!

Comment: @Épicerie Le Pont Vert Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.